# How to convert POJO to XML with Jackson

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson, pojo

I am looking for best solution how to convert POJO or JSON to XML with all atttributes in correct places. For now, Jackson looks like the most convenient way. I am able to serialize POJO to XML without attributes.

POJO TestUser

```
public class TestUser extends JsonType
{
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private final String username;
    @JsonProperty("fullname")
    private final String fullname;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private final String email;
    @JsonProperty("enabled")
    private final Boolean enabled;

    @JsonCreator
    public TestUser(
        @JsonProperty("username") String username, 
        @JsonProperty("fullname") String fullname, 
        @JsonProperty("email") String email,
        @JsonProperty("enabled") Boolean enabled)
        {
            this.username = username;
            this.fullname = fullname;
            this.email = email;
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }
        @JsonGetter("username")
        public String getUsername()
        {
            return username;
        }
        @JsonGetter("fullname")
        public String getFullname()
        {
            return fullname;
        }
        @JsonGetter("email")
        public String getEmail()
        {
            return email;
        }
        @JsonGetter("enabled")
        public Boolean getEnabled()
        {
            return enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
public void testJsonToXML() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
    String jsonInput = "{\"username\":\"FOO\",\"fullname\":\"FOO BAR\", \"email\":\"foobar@foobar.com\", \"enabled\":\"true\"}";

    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TestUser foo = jsonMapper.readValue(jsonInput, TestUser.class);
    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    System.out.println(xmlMapper.writer().with(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE).withRootName("product").writeValueAsString(foo));
}
```

And now it returns this

```
<TestUser xmlns="">
    <product>
        <username>FOO</username>
        <fullname>FOO BAR</fullname>
        <email>foobar@foobar.com</email>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </product>
</TestUser>
```

Which is nice, but I need variable `enabled` to be attribute of `username` and then I need to add xmlns and xsi attributes to the root element so the XML result looks like this

```
<TestUser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="testUser.xsd">
    <product>
        <username enabled="true">FOO</username>
        <fullname>FOO BAR</fullname>
        <email>foobar@foobar.com</email>
    </product>
</TestUser>
```

I found some examples using `@JacksonXmlProperty` but it only adds the attribute to the root element.

Thanks for help

Comment: What is the complete package name for `JsonType` which you are extending in your `TestUser`?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem: injection of additional data. There is no functionality for doing that currently; but I think it'd be possible to add, say, a new attribute in `@JsonRootName` (`schema=URL`?), that would allow addition of a schema mapping or mappings?

I went ahead and filed this:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/90

to add something that should work; feel free to add comments, suggestions.